# What was the role of Apollos in the early church?

Tags: church-history, apostles

In 1 Corinthians 3:6, Paul wrote:

> I planted the seed, Apollos watered it, but God has been making it grow.

Why did Paul specifically mention Apollos as that is the name of a god in Greek mythology?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Apollos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollos) was an Alexandrian Jew, as stated in Acts 18:24 (with following verses indicating that he knew the [Jewish] Scriptures and preached the gospel--"the way of the Lord"--but only knew "the baptism of John" before being further instructed by Priscilla and Aquila).

It is possible that, like Timothy, he had a Jewish mother but a Gentile father; this might explain his being named Apollos. Since Alexandria was a center for both Greek and Jewish cultures, mixed parentage seems plausible.

Answer (score 1):

Apollos was a Hellenized Jew (meaning he most likely only spoke Greek) from Alexandria, Egypt. He was raised under the instruction of Priscilla and Aquila, becoming so prominent that the Corinthian Church had a rift between followers of Paul and followers of Apollos. It was quite common for Hellenized Jews (as well as other people) to have Greek and Latin names during this period, such as Phillip, Andrew, Mark, Priscilla and Aquila, and others.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)